# Java best practice of displaying application version number

Tags: java, continuous-integration, versioning

What is the best practice of displaying the application version number in a Help -> About page within the application? The application is packaged as a EAR file which contains 1 WAR file.

From my research I believe this is to store the information in the Manifest file and then reference this from a application class.

The version number system in use is MAJOR.MINOR.BUILDNUMBER. The BUILDNUMBER is controlled through the Continuous Delivery system and is assigned at commit time based on the revision log number.

This means at development time a BUILDNUMBER will not exist. It doesn't feel right that the version number displayed is different at development time.

Comment: Do you have a particular build system in mind? Maven? Ant?

Comment: I typically read the version number from the Implementation-Version of the manifest. You get this by About.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion(). Then you need to make sure to actually write the build number in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the CI server as just another developer, with the specific task of building the final application.

Information about the build are generated by the CI and contains typically the Git hash and a BUILDNUMBER value, and these values are not known at development time.  So for the "mere mortals" developers we set it at "local" while it's the Jenkins build number for the CI.